# Enum Type in WSDL representation

Tags: java, wsdl

A WSDL representation as below :

```
<xs:simpleType name="customerType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="PRIVATE"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="BUSINESS"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

resulted in the code as below by cxf-codegen-plugin:

```
public enum CustomerType { 
    PRIVATE, BUSINESS 
}
```

Can be represented in WSDL as:

How can we represent enum in WSDL so that the cxf-codegen-plugin can generate code as below:

```
public enum CustomerType { 
        PRIVATE{public BigInteger getNcid() { 
                return new BigInteger("1"); 
}, 
BUSINESS{public BigInteger getNcid() { 
                return new BigInteger("2"); 
} 

public abstract BigInteger getNcid(); 
    }
```

If we can't have cxf-codegen generate this what is the best way we can handle this case in java. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You can find 4 ways to create an enumeration in wdsl and how they work with CXF here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41935803/715269

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not a representation of the same thing.

You haven't said which programming language you're using, but it looks like you intend for PRIVATE to be associated with the value 1, and BUSINESS to be associated with the value 2. That is not represented in the WSDL.

WSDL uses XML Schema to describe the shape of data. XML Schema has no concept equivalent to an `enum` in a programming language. In most programming languages I know, an `enum` is a named constant. The `enumeration` facet in XML Schema does not describe named values. It simply says that the value at that point can be one of the listed (string) values.

Comment: Hi John thanks for the explanation i was actually trying to generate code from WSDL in java using cxf codegen plugin and i don't see a way to generate code as i mentioned above. Do you know of any ways to make codegen realize the enum values associated to them ?

Comment: No, because the Java concept of enum does not exist in XML Schema.

Comment: Thanks John for your clarification