# CXF is not generating enum mapping?

Tags: java, web-services, enums, wsdl, cxf

I'm generating classes with `CXF` (wsdl2java) out of `wsdl` files, but one enum is instead mapped to a `String` only.

If I open the generated class, this is the wsdl snippet:

```
 <complexType>
    <complexContent>
      <restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
        <attribute name="Type" use="required">
          <simpleType>
            <restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string">
              <enumeration value="AAA"/>
              <enumeration value="VVV"/>
            </restriction>
          </simpleType>
        </attribute>
      </restriction>
    </complexContent>
  </complexType>
```

Why is the result a `String`, and not an `Enum`?
This is the auto generated result:

```
private String type;

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String value) {
    this.type = value;
}
```

Update: custom binding file:

```
<jaxb:bindings    
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    jaxb:version="2.1">


         <jaxb:bindings>
                <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:attribute[@name='Type']/xs:simpleType">
                 <jaxb:typesafeEnumClass ref="TestEnum" />
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Comment: Because you explicitly mention String in your bean class

Comment: Sure, <restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"> change this

Comment: you have a binding xml file in your wisdl xml files, you need to bind string with enum in there on your desired types

Comment: you need to put string not simpletype

Comment: in your xml binding file

Comment: You mean `//xs:attribute[@name='Type']/xs:string`???

Comment: Nop, this <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:attribute[@name='Type']/xs:simpleType">

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean with "you need to put string not simpletype"... Could you provide an example what I'd have to change?

Comment: this <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:attribute[@name='Type']/xs:simpleType"> to this <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:attribute[@name='Type']/xs:string">

Comment: That results in the following error message: `XPath evaluation results in empty target node`

Answer (score 5):

The following information appeared as a result of my experiments. I couldn't find anything useful in the CXF manuals.

- if you declare a type inside another type, and it is `simpletype`, you have NO type in the container java class, but only a field. If your restriction was based on `string`, you will have the field of the `String` type.
- if that inner type is `complextype` (you must put a `simplecontent` element between `complextype` and `restriction`), you have an inner class with the correct name, but it is NOT a real enumeration. You can get a String value by `getValue()`. You can use any string data for it and get no error. (IMHO, absolutely useless variant)
- if you declare your enumeration as a `complextype` without container type, you will have it as a public not-inner class. Otherwards, it is as the previous. Again, it is no enumeration, no check for correctness, no real restrictions. Useless.
- if you declare your enumeration type outside of any container type, and it will be a `simpletype`, you have a public non-inner enumeration. Obviously, it is what you would like to see.

What is worse, even the fourth variant won't catch an error in an XML message for you. If:

```
enumeration StyleType {A,B,C}
...
StyleType Style
```

And you have XML message with incorrect (not one of A,B,C) value for Style, you will simply get null when using `getStyle()`. So, instead of having nice message "in ... message on line ... position ... there are incorrect data",  you have to add a check for not null after every gerStyle(). If you don't want the user to get `NullPointerException`'s.

Answer (score 4):

> "... one enum is instead mapped to a String only."
>
> "Why is the result a String, and not an Enum?"

This could happen when one of your enumeration value is not a valid Java identifier (for instance: starts with digit) - JAXB (which cxf's `wsdl2java` delegates work to) is de facto forced to use `String` field, otherwise generated code wouldn't compile.

Recommended reading: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/jaxb-and-enums.html