# JAX-WS No Enum generated parsing WSDL with list of restrictions (enums)

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, schema, jax-ws

In case WSDL type definition is following:

```
<xs:simpleType name="AccountStatus">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="Open" />
        <xs:enumeration value="Closed" />
        <xs:enumeration value="CreditOnly" />
        <xs:enumeration value="BudgetOnly" />
        <xs:enumeration value="Frozen" />
        <xs:enumeration value="Reserved" />
        <xs:enumeration value="Cancelled" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Ordinary Java enum AccountStatus gets generated in client classes.

But when definition is changed to list of this enums as following:

```
<xs:simpleType name="AccountStatus">
    <xs:list>
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="Open"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="Closed"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="CreditOnly"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="BudgetOnly"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="Frozen"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="Reserved" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Cancelled" />
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:list>
</xs:simpleType>
```

No enum class is generated for AccountStatus. On the object itself that is supposed to have account statuses list. Currently it has

```
List<List<String>> statuses
```

Instead of

```
List<AccountStatus> statuses
```

Comment: You can find 4 ways to create an enumeration in wdsl and how they work with CXF here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41935803/715269

Answer (score 1):

I am generating client from third party vendor Web Services WSDL, that I cannot alter. So far I found the way of managing my issue with JAXB Bindings:

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../main/resources/META-INF/wsdl/AccountsService.wsdl#types?schema4" node=".//xs:simpleType[@name='AccountStatus']/xs:list/xs:simpleType">
    <jxb:typesafeEnumClass name="AccountStatus">
        <jxb:typesafeEnumMember value="Open" name="Open" />
        <jxb:typesafeEnumMember value="Closed" name="Closed" />
        <jxb:typesafeEnumMember value="CreditOnly" name="CreditOnly" />
        <jxb:typesafeEnumMember value="BudgetOnly" name="BudgetOnly" />
        <jxb:typesafeEnumMember value="Frozen" name="Frozen" />
        <jxb:typesafeEnumMember value="Reserved" name="Reserved" />
        <jxb:typesafeEnumMember value="Cancelled" name="Cancelled" />
    </jxb:typesafeEnumClass>
</jxb:bindings>
```

It is important to write correct XPath query and the result is:

```
List<AccountStatus> statuses
```

code generated on client stub classes.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `xs:list` before, but as I understand it, your're actually defining `AccountStatus` as a list of strings.

Instead, I'd do the following:

```xml
<xs:simpleType name="AccountStatus">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="Open" />
        <xs:enumeration value="Closed" />
        <xs:enumeration value="CreditOnly" />
        <xs:enumeration value="BudgetOnly" />
        <xs:enumeration value="Frozen" />
        <xs:enumeration value="Reserved" />
        <xs:enumeration value="Cancelled" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:complexType name="AccountStatusHolder">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="status" type="tns:AccountStatus" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Notice the **maxOccurs="unbounded"** setting, resulting in the following class (JAXB generated):

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "AccountStatusHolder", propOrder = "status")
public class AccountStatusHolder implements Serializable {
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 0L;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected List<AccountStatus> status;
}
```